# Setting Up A Wired Internet Connection

Tags: internet, ethernet, internet-connection, wired-networking

I am trying to setup up a wired internet network in my home. I have a modem/router combo that the internet company installed. If I plug directly into this, or log onto the wifi I get a great connection. However I would like a good connection two floors above as well. Luckily my home is wired with ethernet (or so it seems) -- there are cat5 ports in several of the rooms. So I plugged an ethernet cable from the one of the "outgoing" ports on the modem/router device into one of these cat5 ports in my wall. I then plugged my computer into one of these cat5 ports several rooms away. I was hoping my computer would then recognize this connection and be able to get online but this is not the case :/. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to know about using a built in ethernet cable system? Is there any kind of setup process?

Comment: First guess: These cat5 ports for each room go to corresponding labelled cat5 ports in a central room or closet. You need to set up a switch or router in this central place to connect the ports correctly (or at least connect them with patch cables). Expecting all cat5 ports in all rooms to be "connected to each other" is usually not how it works.

Answer (score 2):

*Usually,* these ports aren't simply wired directly to each other. A modern Ethernet connection needs to have exactly two ends – you can't just put a whole bunch of ports on the same cable. (Only old 10BASE2 used to work this way.)

Instead, it's likely that every port has its own cable and they're all going *somewhere* to a central location, maybe a patch panel in a closet or just a thick bundle of cables in some hidden spot, and you are supposed to install an Ethernet switch there. (Maybe there already is a dusty old switch that isn't powered on.)

(If you can't find it, there are "cable tracer" devices which might help.)

Once the switch is in place, all ports should be able to talk to each other, so just connect one of them to the ISP-provided router and the rest to your computers.

---

However, not all houses have Cat5 jacks that are *actually* wired for Ethernet... it could be that they only have telephone wiring behind them (or something else, or nothing at all).